# GnuTLS ServerHello exploit (CVE-2014-3466) - how to verify?

Tags: tls, linux, attack-prevention, kali-linux

So pretty much all of the GNUTLS world is worrying about CVE-2014-3466. I checked my Kali and it responds with this -

```
# apt-cache rdepends libgnutls26 | grep -v lib
Reverse Depends:
  telepathy-gabble
  qemu-kvm
  guile-gnutls
  gnutls-bin
  xxxterm
  xpp
  xfprint4
  xfce4-mailwatch-plugin
  xen-utils-4.1
  x11vnc
  wzdftpd-mod-tcl
  wzdftpd-mod-perl
  wzdftpd-back-pgsql
  wzdftpd-back-mysql
  wzdftpd
  wmbiff
  wget
  weechat-curses
  weechat-core
  webfs
  vpnc
  vlc-nox
  vino
  ucommon-utils
  totem-plugins
  telepathy-salut
  telepathy-gabble
  tdsodbc
  suricata
  sogo
  snort-pgsql
  snort-mysql
  snort
  slapd
  sipwitch-cgi
  sipwitch
  sipsak
  shishi-kdc
  shishi
  shisa
  scrollz
  samhain
  rtmpdump
  rsyslog-gnutls
  qpdfview
  qemu-system-x86
  qemu-system-sparc
  qemu-system-ppc
  qemu-system-misc
  qemu-system-mips
  qemu-system-arm
  python-pycurl-dbg
  python-pycurl
  python-preludedb
  python-prelude
  python-mailutils
  python-gtk-vnc
  python-gnutls
  proxytunnel
  printer-driver-gutenprint
  prelude-manager
  prelude-lml
  postal
  pianobar
  passing-the-hash
  pacemaker
  openvas-scanner
  openvas-manager
  openvas-cli
  openvas-administrator
  nzbget
  nullmailer
  ntfs-3g
  ngircd
  newsbeuter
  network-manager
  netatalk
  nautilus-sendto-empathy
  mutt-patched
  mutt
  msmtp-gnome
  msmtp
  mpop-gnome
  mpop
  mozilla-gtk-vnc
  minbif
  mandos-client
  mailutils-pop3d
  mailutils-mh
  mailutils-imap4d
  mailutils-comsatd
  mailutils
  macopix-gtk2
  lynx-cur
  linuxvnc
  lftp
  ldap-utils
  kildclient
  jd
  ircd-ratbox
  inspircd
  infinoted
  heartbeat
  gvncviewer
  gurlchecker
  guile-gnutls
  gtklp
  gtk-gnutella
  gsd
  gsasl
  greenbone-security-assistant
  gobby-0.5
  gnutls-bin
  gnu-smalltalk
  gnomint
  gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-control-center
  gkrellm
  ghostscript-cups
  freetds-bin
  filezilla
  exim4-daemon-light
  exim4-daemon-heavy
  empathy
  elinks-lite
  elinks
  ekg2-remote
  ekg2-jabber
  echoping
  dsyslog
  cups
  csync2
  connman
  claws-mail-trayicon
  claws-mail-spamassassin
  claws-mail-smime-plugin
  claws-mail-pgpmime
  claws-mail-pgpinline
  claws-mail-bogofilter
  claws-mail
  charybdis
  centerim-utf8
  centerim-fribidi
  centerim
  cairo-dock-mail-plug-in
  bitlbee
  ario
  aria2
  anubis
  aiccu
  abiword
```

There are a few POCs around - https://github.com/azet/CVE-2014-3466_PoC/blob/master/poc.py and http://radare.today/technical-analysis-of-the-gnutls-hello-vulnerability/.

My question is other than launching the POC, how do I check for vulnerable machines? What if gnutls-cli is not present?

Comment: Just check it using your systems' local package manager for the current version of GnuTLS...

Answer (score 1):

Typically you verify a vulnerability in three ways:

1. Run exploit code. Did it blow up?
2. Check your package manager's documentation. Do you have their version?
3. Check the code. Do you have the affected lines?

Since #3 is not effective for binaries, and you do not want to run exploit code, your other option is updating. I'd imagine by now that every distro has released new versions or backported patches for the GnuTLS packages, so a simple update command should identify and patch affected machines.